# Comparison between WDS and Wired Router

Tags: router, wireless, ieee-802.11

I'm considering to set-up a hotspot(With Mikrotik RB951) in a place that has 4 floors so I should extend the wireless signal. 
I bought 4 wireless Routers (TP-Link WR841HP) That I want to put in each floor (200 square-meter) and I need roaming as well. 
with two solutions, I can implement it :

1. by cabling the routers together
2. using WDS

it is better that I cabling but performance is more important.
less that 200 users use this hotspot to connect max 8Mbps internet connection. 
My questions listed below :

1. Apparantly WDS is not wifi Certified and it has come with some issues. does it mean I cannot trust this protocol? (by knowing that all router are the same)
2. If my first (main) router is in the first floor and I want to connect fourth floor router to it, can I just connect it to the third floor and it direct me to the main router (1st) or I should see the signal of first router directly? if I can how about performance?
3. comparison between these solutions?

I would appreciate if you help me to find a good practice? 
Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Wireless_WDS_Mesh

Personally I prefer cabling everything and use Wifi strictly for user's traffic not 'backbone' traffic, thus eliminating any lost performance due to that.

Forget connecting routers from first floor to forth floor wirelessly. It will never work properly when you have tons of concrete and metal in between.

Use ethernet to connect all routers together. Also, while maybe desirable, you don't need to connect everything to the main router. You can 'daisy chain' the boards together from one floor to another to reduce the cabling, and use bridges to make everything look as if they where all connected to a switch.

Regarding WDS, I've never had a problem with it, but I haven't used it extensively either. Since you are using Mikrotik on all routers/access points you won't have any compatibility issues. WDS works just fine on Mikrotik.

Comment: you might be able to use PoE in the router daisy chain, if that's any help...